# Configuring JDK in Eclipse -- can this be done in Maven instead?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I import a project I still have to configure a JDK in order to compile but what I would rather do is have this information already present in the imported project itself -- is this possible? Perhaps via Maven?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would configure the `maven-compiler-plugin` for this. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
      <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```